# Codificação de quebra de linha (\n) em Javascript alert()

Tags: php, javascript, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8

Olá,

Estou precisando fazer um replace na string `</script>` transformando-a na string `\n`. O problema é que infelizmente o meu projeto em PHP está com `charset=ISO-8859-1`, enquanto o javascript é executado com `UTF8`.

Qual código ou caractere posso usar para representar o `\n` na conversão do código abaixo?

```
str = str.replace(/\<\/script>/g, encodeURIComponent(String("\n")));
```

Veja como a string é exibida por um alert após a conversão?

```
Erro ao enviar email. %5CnErro ao enviar email. %5CnO seu chamado foi cadastrado com sucesso!
```

E como eu queria que ela fosse imprimida:

```
Erro ao enviar email. 
Erro ao enviar email. 
O seu chamado foi cadastrado com sucesso!
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nem a codificação UTF-8 e nem a ISO-8859-1 interferem nos caracteres de 0x00 até 0x79, e isso inclui os caracteres de controle como tab, cr, lf e demais. O problema do seu código é o uso incorreto do `str.replace`.

Eis algumas possíveis soluções, dependendo do resultado desejado:

```
str = str.replace("</script>", "\n", "g" );
str = str.replace("</script>", "<br>\n", "g" );

// Se preferir trocar tanto `</script>` quanto `</SCRIPT>` e outras combinações,
// acrescente a flag `i`:
str = str.replace("</script>", "<br>\n", "gi" );
```

Alguns browsers não se simpatizam com a flag "g" (global) passada como string, mas é possível usar a sintaxe com *regex* literal para contornar o problema:

```
str = str.replace( /\<\/script>/gi, "<br>\n" );
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @Bacco. O exemplo funcionou perfeitamente para mim.

Answer (score -1):

Acabei de pegar algo parecido, eu solucionei colocando `\\n`
a primeira `\` indica que virá um caractere especial em seguida, no caso só `\n` ele tenta ler o n como caractere especial.